# Android alarm running but not at when seconds are zero?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm making an alarm application. Alarm is running ok. For example If I set the alarm at **06:00 PM** it executes at **06:00 PM**. The problem is that alarm is not executing when seconds are exactly zero. Sometimes it's running at 32 seconds (06:00:32 PM) sometimes at other seconds etc.

In my main activity, I have set alarm save button, when I click on that the following code executes:

```
buttonSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(),
                    pickerDate.getMonth(),
                    pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(),
                    pickerTime.getCurrentHour(),
                    pickerTime.getCurrentMinute(),
                    00);

            if(cal.compareTo(current) <= 0){
                //The set Date/Time already passed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Invalid Date/Time",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                setAlarm(cal);
            }

        }});
```

SetAlarm Method inside main activity is:

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

    info.setText("\n\n***\n"
            + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
            + "***\n");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60, pendingIntent);
}
```

In my AlarmReceiver BroadCastReceiver I have following onReceive Method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Ideas on where my problem should be?

Comment: Can you precise the version of android you are using to test your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with API 19 (KitKat), alarms are *inexact* by default.  If your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 19 or higher, this behavior will be used.  See the note in the docs for the `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` method:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

So your best bet is to use exact one-shot alarms and each time it expires set your alarm again accordingly.

Comment: So It means it can run after 2, 3 minutes or more, according to the OS?

Comment: With inexact alarms, they are batched together with other alarms to minimize how often the system is waking up.  So they can be delayed several seconds or several minutes.

Comment: I have recently check an alarm app on my cell. Which is pinch perfect and runs alarm when seconds are exactly zero. Can you hint me out how they have achieved this

Comment: I have put my target sdk to 18. Now it is working  fine... thanks alot

Comment: Np, glad you were able to get past it. The other way around it is to use single-shot, exact alarms which then schedule another alarm when they expire.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

```
Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.
```